# SMS/MMS Bluetooth and Windows

Tags: windows-8, bluetooth, windows-10-preview

I got a new phone and for the fun of it, I paired it with my laptop (Windows 10 -but anything windows 8 will work too). When I did, I found that the Galaxy S5 supported "sms/mms message access". What can I use with this? I see programs that I can install on the phone and PC, but what supports the built in Bluetooth?